# Loop over year data

Tags: sas

I have the following issue. I want to calculate value for each month in the the data containing all year. but I do not really want to export all month to the separate tables.

Is there any way to make it work with for loop or any other one?

```
data BD.data2017r; 
  retain Open; 
  retain Close;
  set BD.data2017 end=eof curobs=observ1;
  if observ1 = 1 then do; 
    Open = Close; 
  end; 
  if eof then do; 
    Close = Close; 
  end; 
  absout = Close - Open; 
  relative = (Close - Open)/Open; 
run;
```

Comment: I don't agree with or understand the down-votes.  The code isn't very good and the question is basic, but it's a "good" question all in all.  It presents the problem well and presents a limited scope problem.  This is what we want novice users to be doing.

Answer (score 2):

A do until loop can process a by-group and maintain marker values without a need for retaining variables or explicit output:

```
data have;
  do date = '01jan2015'd to '31dec2016'd;
    month = intnx('month',date,0);
    close + 1;
    output;
  end;
  format date yymmdd10. month yymmd7.;
run;

data want;
  do until (last.month);
    set have;
    by month;
    if first.month then open = close;
  end;

  range = close - open;
  relative = range / open;

  keep month open close range relative;
run;
```

A non-do loop approach that does the same would need to retain the open value and requires an explicit output statement.

```
data want2;
  set have;
  by month;

  retain open;
  if first.month then
    open = close;

  if last.month then do;
    range = close - open;
    relative = range / open;
    OUTPUT;
  end;

  keep month open close range relative;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the data is sorted by date you can use BY-group processing (`by month_var`), with `first.month_var` and `last.month_var` as the markers indicating the the start and end of each BY-group (i.e. month).

You'll also need to explicitly `output;` one row for each month in the `if last.month_var` block.